# Angular D3 - Property 'getBoundingClientRect' does not exist on type 'Window'

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I have a stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-tootltip-ocdngb?file=src/app/bar-chart.ts

I have a D3 chart in and angular app.

The bars show tooltip when hovering over them.

On smaller screens the tooltip is in the center of the window.

To do this I need the with of the tooltip which I get with

```
const toolTipWidth = tooltip.node().getBoundingClientRect().width;
```

This is works fine here but my actual app is an Angular cli app

The app still runs but I get the error

```
error TS2339: Property 'getBoundingClientRect' does not exist on type 'BaseType'.
  Property 'getBoundingClientRect' does not exist on type 'Window'.
```

Was is it error and can I stop it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could simply cast the `tooltip.node()` as `any` to get around this:

```
const toolTipWidth = (tooltip.node() as any).getBoundingClientRect().width;
```

Correct type should be probably `HTMLElement`, that should work too:

```
const toolTipWidth = (tooltip.node() as HTMLElement).getBoundingClientRect().width;
```